# Why will my code not store more than two data fields?

Tags: php, html

I'm currently learning PHP and mySQL for a project over the summer. I'm trying to create a HTML form that will store 4 text fields into a mySQL table. This is the code I'm using:

**HTML Form**

```
<form action="postEvent.php" method="post">
    Name:
    <input type="text" name="Name" />
    Date: 
    <input type="text" name="Date" />
    Time:
    <input type="text" name"Time"  />
    Description: 
    <input type="text" name"Description" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**PHP Action**

```
// Create connection
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '******', 'myDB');

// Check connection
if ($link->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $link->connect_error);
}

$iName = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['Name']);
$iDate = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['Date']);
$iTime = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['Time']);
$iDescription = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['Description']);
$sql = "INSERT INTO events "
    . "(Name,Date,Time,Description)"
    . " VALUES ('$iName','$iDate','$iTime','$iDescription')";

if (mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $link->error;
}

$link->close();
```

I set up my database using Microsoft WebMatrix and I'm running it locally from my machine. Each field within the database uses the same data type.

My issue is that when I run the code it only stores the first two text fields. The Time and Description are submitted as blank to table.

Comment: add print_r($_POST) at the top of postEvent.php and post the output in the question.

Comment: `$sql = "INSERT INTO events (Name,Date,Time,Description) VALUES 
            ('$iName','$iDate','$iTime','$iDescription')";` is better

Comment: @MawiaHL
I've added both suggestions, entered some random text and the page printed the following:

_Array ( [Name] => hjjhgjh [Date] => kljklj ) New record created successfully_

Comment: @ Miwia NL. I dont see how it s better...

Comment: typo in html: `<input type="text" name"Time"  />` missing the `=` there! So `$_POST['Time']` throws undefined index error.

Comment: @Jeff that is the solution please post it as an answer :)

Comment: @BenWyatt, see my answer below.

Comment: @MawiaHL already posted it the same as an answer, we spottet it together :) You can accept his answer! (or you might aswell delete it, as it was a simple typo - though the additional if empty checks are worth keeping it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form should look like below. I add `name="submit"` in the submit button

```
<form action="postEvent.php" method="post">
    Name:
    <input type="text" name="Name" />
    Date: 
    <input type="text" name="Date" />
    Time:
    <input type="text" name="Time"  />
    Description: 
    <input type="text" name="Description" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

and here is the Postevent.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
       $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "my_password", "myDB");
       $name = isset($_POST['Name'])? $_POST['Name']:'';
       $date= isset($_POST['Date'])? $_POST['Date']:'';
       $time= isset($_POST['Time'])? $_POST['Time']:'';
       $des= isset($_POST['Description'])? $_POST['Description']:'';    

      if(empty($name)){
        $error = 'Enter Name';
      }elseif(empty($date)){
        $error = 'Enter date';
      }elseif(empty($time)){
        $error ='Enter time';
      }elseif(empty($des)){
        $error = 'Enter description';
      }else{
        $query = "INSERT INTO `events` (`Name`, `Date`, `Time`, `Description`) 
                  VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $name, $date, $time,$des);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
      }
    }
```

And you can check if there is error:

```
if(!empty($error)){
    echo $error;
}
```